# Get width and height of the device in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I need a reliable way to get the dimensions of the screen.

I know **MediaQuery.of(context)**, but it removes the bottom padding when the bottom UI item is visible.

Comment: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407

Comment: @diegoveloper what? it's about the size of the widget

Comment: What do you mean 'bottom UI item'?

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom

Comment: @diegoveloper I've tried this one

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString() + " - " + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom.toString());

padding.bottom always returns with 0 to me

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Sorry, I meant the SystemUiOverlay.bottom, i'm not sure how it's called in android

Comment: ah, haven't used that myself. What about `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`. If you open a keyboard, that's what it shows up as using.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie No success :( both viewInsets and padding returns with EdgeInsets.zero...

Comment: I can solve this like this:
MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
But i really believe there should be a better solution...

Comment: Hmmm. That's starting to sound like a bug, although it might be because the underlying activity that's managing flutter is actually reduced in size when the bottom is shown.  And using `devicePixelRatio` isn't what you want either, as it the number of device pixels per logical pixels, not the aspect ratio of the screen....

Comment: ummm. try `import 'dart:ui' as ui;` and `ui.window.physicalSize`. Although I think that's what mediaquery is using under the hood

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Yeah, probably you were right.

I've just used ui.window.physicalSize, but it returns with the same values.
ui.window.padding is the same story

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be impossible from within dart at the moment on Android due to flutter ignoring the bottom system UI (i.e. the buttons).

I thought this might be a bug, but if you look closely at the documentation it never states that `window.physicalSize` or `MediaQueryData.size` are the physical dimensions of the screen, but rather the size to which flutter can render. That probably makes sense, or else every single app would have to make sure to take that into account.

So what you're going to have to do is [use method channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to communicate with android directly. I took a look already and there doesn't appear to be any plugins doing this, so you could wrap it up into one if you feel ambitious. But what you'll want to do is make a call to native and then get the physical screen size directly in java code. If you do that you'd probably be best off implementing it for iOS as well, although this same problem doesn't exist there (you could even do it directly in flutter with an if/else).

Luckily, someone has done this before so you can use it as an example: https://github.com/magnatronus/flutter-displaymetrics. Assuming that displayMetrics gives you the right size.

Hope that helps and sorry I don't have a simpler answer for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help man.
Hope there will be a better solution soon though.

Comment: It might be worth raising a bug with the flutter people over on GitHub, but I've a pretty strong feeling they'll say it's enough of a corner case that someone can just write a plugin for it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've published plugin, that can help you to get the dimensions of the screen, and other display metrics, such as PPI and diagonal, also it will help you to convert inches & cm to Flutter logical pixels.
You can try it here https://pub.dev/packages/display_metrics